# Generalist - A Silver Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

The [Generalist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) badge states that:

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.

Bringing in the badge descriptions here for sake of analysis.

Silver Badges:

> Silver badges are less common than bronze ones. You'll need to plan your strategy to get one of these.

And the Gold Badges:

> Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.

Now, in my opinion, I feel that the Generalist badge is one of the most difficult badges on S.O. due to the need for not only questions/answers in the top forty tags, but well received ones.

On to interpreting the badge types, one can approach the badge types one of two ways

The usual medal approach

- Bronze < Silver < Gold

Or the interpreted badge description (my interpretation)

- Bronze Badges: Shows that users use features well on an "introductory" level
- Silver Badges: Shows that the users know how to plan to use those features
- Gold Badges: Shows significant user contribution regardless of planning or not

I guess overall my question is, why is the generalist badge only a silver badge and why was it set that way?

[Generalist Badge Progress Query - See The Top 40 Tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/33647/generalist-badge)

Comment: It is much more difficult than the others. Only 540 ever awarded http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges. Dupe of uber meta discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50925

Comment: @MartinSmith it is third to the [Epic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic) and [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) tags, surprisingly.

Comment: True Epic is silver as well.

Comment: Archaeologist is also silver has only 700 awarded; many badge levels don't accurately reflect how many people have won them.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Which in my opinion, falls under the interpreted descriptions. But then, why are we using the cliche bronze/silver/gold paradigm?

Comment: It should, of course, be a gold badge - but those of us who have earned it are, naturally, too intellectual to worry about badges :)

Comment: IMO it should swap places with the gold badge "unsung hero" which is relatively easy to get - and then I'm proving I'm intellectual because that's the only gold badge I have ;)

Comment: I would like both of them to be gold badges. ;)

Comment: _"IMO it should swap places with the gold badge "unsung hero" which is relatively easy to get"_. I have no opinion on whether "unsung hero" should be a gold badge, or exist at all. I would, however, argue that it isn't easy to get per se. In fact, I'm not sure what kind of strategy one would employ if you were actively trying to get that badge. It's probably a badge that people tend to get by "chance", and often much earlier than other gold badges, which could leave the impression that it was easy to get.

Comment: A side question: Why is getting a badge so important for SO users?

Comment: @reporter It's like getting a special epic mount in WoW it's fun, and it makes you look cool.

Comment: I would contest your definition of the gold badge, many gold badges are not rewarded just because you spammed a lot of questions/answers/edits quite a few are but not all

Comment: @reporter If you have to ask, you don't get it. Badges are formalized nerd coolness. Think of you number of points as a rank, and your badges as medals. http://imgur.com/2XNa2Il

Comment: @Sammaye By `Regardless of planning or not`, I meant that users either efficiently use the site with the explicit goal of getting the badge OR they simply use the site efficiently and get the badge as a consequence.

Comment: Have any badges been recolored since the site launched?  SE assigned the original bronze/silver/gold ratings based on a combination of guess work and the limited information available from the beta.  IMO it's more surprising how many they got right than that there a few that are wrong.  Now days, new badges are relatively easy to get right because they've got multiple years of user data to test against.

Comment: Take into account the badges are used *across the network* and may be easier or harder to earn on different sites. I would already qualify for the Generalist badge on Meta.SO if it weren't for the '40 tags with at least 200 questions each' requirement.

Comment: Could also just make it easier to get and add a new gold badge with the same or similar requirements to Generalist now say 'Know It All'

Comment: @EricPetroelje I agree, I believe reducing the requirements for another badge to something lke 115 total score in 10 of top 40 tags.1 and boosting Generalist to a gold badge would be the best way to handle this. (And there will be more badges!)