# What is a non-wiki answer?

Tags: support, badges

I was reading about the meaning of different badges at https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges. For the *Generalist* badge the help page says:

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

But I cannot understand this, because I do not know what a *non-wiki* answer is.

The question: [Generalist - A Silver Badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272010/generalist-a-silver-badge) is about the *Generalist* badge, but in that question the meaning of 'non-wiki' is not explained.

What is a non-wiki answer?

Comment: In addition to Second Rikudo's answer see [this help centre article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

Answer (score 15):

This is a wiki answer. Anything that's not this.

(There's a small checkbox at the bottom right of the answer textbox.

[image: Freehand circles and arrows!]

Community wiki answers are basically answers that most people (even with lower reputations) can edit and improve upon. Generally, they can add upon these answers very quickly, without getting stuck in review queues. It's an answer where virtually the *entire* community can add to.

People don't get reputation changes from these answers either - in any direction.  This means that a downvote on a Community Wiki does not count against either the downvoter or the post itself, nor would an upvote or accept [result in any reputation awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/175248).

Since, everyone can expand on them, it makes sense to call them wiki, they may include many points for a great answer. This paragraph was written by a user other than the original author, and shows how nice community wikis are. :)

A non-wiki can simply be thought of as a post that is solely your own, and doesn't include what was said in the paragraph above.

Comment: Thanks. Let me just confirm. It is is a 'wiki' answer if you check the 'community wiki' checkbox while answering. And it is a  'non-wiki' answer if you do NOT check the 'community wiki' checkbox while answering. Am i right ?

Comment: I just read the link shared by Martin above. So i guess yes its a non-wiki answer if you do not check that 'community-wiki' checkbox. thanks.

Comment: They can convert regular posts to community wikis I believe.

Comment: You're right! Of course, there is some tweaks to it (questions with > 30 answers become community wikis), but that's the *general* idea! <- see what I did there! I know, I'll stop... I'll mention that this is a great example of a community wiki: A great comprehensive answer, which has information add by (at the time of this writing), 3 users! (including myself)

Comment: @Zizouz212:  That automatic trigger no longer exists.

Comment: Oh, then never mind that!